# How can I prevent glare on my PSP 3000?

Tags: psp

My PSP 3000 is almost impossible to play in the car because of the extreme glare.
It's like looking into a mirror on bright day and it's pretty much unplayable.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Have you tried increasing the brightness in the console?
- If its your car you can always keep a small towel handy in it. Cover yourself and the console with it.
- While travelling in other vehicles have someone else sit next to the window while you sit towards the center. This way the outdoor light will be less of an obstruction.
- Hold your psp in different inclines till one feels a good balance of outside light vs your psp screen.

Whatever you do try not to strain your eyes for long durations or you could damage your eyesight. I know because I got eye power long time back due to a strenuous game.

Comment: These are great suggestions, but some aren't very practical. I have adjusted the brightness to maximum, and holding the psp in different positions didn't really help. I definitely agree about eye strain though. It's not even worth it for me to try to play in the car.

Comment: Its surprising to know you had this problem with the psp 3000 which boasts 5 times increased contrast from the previous version. Well, nothing's perfect I guess.

Comment: From what I read only the initial psp 3000's have this problem. They updated them at some point in 2009 with a brighter screen.

Answer (score 2):

There are anti-glare kits on the market you can buy and install yourself.
Some shops even might offer the service of installing it themselves by sending your PSP in.

One example I just google'd up: http://www.photodon.com/p/MXT-2205-01-Bulk.html

I'm sure you will find the most suitable one for your needs.

Comment: That solution costs almost as much as my psp. I don't really see it as an option. Thanks for trying though.